# Can't find my meteor App in my docker image

Tags: meteor, docker

I have used this docker image [DanielDent/docker-meteor](https://github.com/DanielDent/docker-meteor) to create my first meteor app in a docker container. It works well when we run the image to create a container then to create a meteor app using this command `meteor create myfirstapp` and I'm able to edit js, css and html files. By typing `meteor` command I'm able to reach my app on the browser.

I took a snapshot from my container and used that image to create a new one. However, when I log in to the new container, I didn't find my first app.

Could you help on this?

Comment: The snapshot was taken using `docker commit`, right?

Comment: Yes, the snapshot was taken using `commit` command